# Assign values to Int Array (without repeating!)

Tags: c#

I need to assign values to an IntArray with 1000 elements randomly. But the elements cannot be repeated. I used this code...

```
public int[] Numbers()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int check;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        check = random.Next(0, 9999);

        while (!numbers.Contains(check))
        {
            numbers[i] = check;
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

But then, an amount of numbers get the default values (0). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to translate that part xD

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is slightly off - if the Contains() fails, you need to still assign that index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    check = random.Next(0, 9999);

    while (numbers.Contains(check))
    {
        // The number existed, so recompute...
        check = random.Next(0, 9999);
    }

    numbers[i] = check;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're skipping over entries if they already exist, which is why they are 0. Change your `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    check = random.Next(0, 9999)
    while (numbers.Contains(check))
    {
        check = random.Next(0, 9999)
    }

    numbers[i] = check;
}
```

Although a more performant (trades memory versus loops over `numbers`) means of generating N distinct random numbers:

```
int ii = 0;
var numbers = new int[N];
var used = new HashSet<int>(); // much faster on lookups than Array.Contains
while (used.Count < N)
{
    var check = random.Next();
    if (used.Add(check)) numbers[ii++] = check;
    // alternatively: if (used.Add(numbers[ii] = check)) ii++;
}

return numbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the check fails you skip a number. Change the loop so that if the check fails you generate a new number before the loop continues

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, although it is not necessarily the most performant:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).Take(1000).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to look at this will be to shuffle an order array of 1000 items 
You can use something like this:

```
        public T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
        {
                var random = _random;
                for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
                {
                        // Pick random element to swap.
                        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
                        // Swap.
                        T tmp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[i - 1];
                        array[i - 1] = tmp;
                }
                return array;
        }
```

and then use it like that

```
                int[] values = new int[1000]
                for (int i=0; i<999; i++)
                   values[i] = i;

                values = Shuffle<int>(values);
                foreach (int item in values)
                {
                        Response.Write(item);
                }
                Response.Write("</br>");
                values = Shuffle<int>(values);
                foreach (int item in values)
                {
                        Response.Write(item); //this will generate a unique random from 0-999
                }
```

code example taken from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1778021.aspx/1)

Comment: Shuffling an array and generating 1000 unique random numbers are two mutually exclusive goals.

Comment: OP wants 1000 distinct integers between 0 and 9999. How do you fill the array before shuffling it to achieve this?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: If you have a sorted array of 1000 distinct integers, you can shuffle it to get a random permutation.

Comment: just fill an array with a simple loop from 0-9999 and the shuffle it.

Comment: @Mortalus: 0-9999 is 10,000 numbers.

Comment: @Mortalus: That sounds easier than it is. If you already have an array with 1000 distinct integers between 0-9999, then you don't need to shuffle it.

Comment: the meaning of having an array of 1000 items which are all distinct is to have an array that contains numbers from 0-999 isn't it ? so from this point you can just run through the array linearly with a foreach loop and the response.write actually generates a distinct value from 0-999

Comment: @dtb: if the OP's problem was turning 1000 sorted distinct numbers into a random permutation...then certainly shuffling is the right answer. If the OP's problem is generating 1000 distinct random numbers, I don't see how Fisher-Yates is going to help in solving their problem.

Comment: @Mortalus: But the requirement is not 0-999. It's 0-9999.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Right.

Comment: okay so create an array of 10,000 numbers you'll get the same result for any given range from 0....n